# python: grouping or splitting up time series data based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, python-itertools

I work a lot with time series data at my job and I have been trying to use python--specifically pandas--to make some of the work a little faster. I have some code that reads through data in a `DataFrame` and identifies segments where specified conditions are met. It then separates those segments into individual DataFrames.

I have a sample `DataFrame` here:

```
        Date      Time  Pressure   Temp  Flow  Valve Position
0   3/5/2020  12:00:01      5.32  22.12   199            1.00
1   3/5/2020  12:00:02      5.36  22.25   115            0.95
2   3/5/2020  12:00:03      5.33  22.18   109            0.92
3   3/5/2020  12:00:04      5.38  23.51   103            0.90
4   3/5/2020  12:00:05      5.42  24.27    99            0.89
5   3/5/2020  12:00:06      5.49  25.91    92            0.85
6   3/5/2020  12:00:07      5.55  26.78    85            0.82
7   3/5/2020  12:00:08      5.61  29.88    82            0.76
8   3/5/2020  12:00:09      5.69  31.16    87            0.79
9   3/5/2020  12:00:10      5.72  32.01    97            0.87
10  3/5/2020  12:00:11      5.59  29.68   104            0.90
11  3/5/2020  12:00:12      5.53  24.55   111            0.93
12  3/5/2020  12:00:13      5.48  23.54   116            0.96
13  3/5/2020  12:00:14      5.44  23.11   119            1.00
14  3/5/2020  12:00:15      5.41  23.08   121            1.00
```

The code I have written does what I want but is really difficult to follow and I am sure its offensive to experienced python users.

Here is what it does though: 
I more or less create a mask based on a set of conditions and I take the index locations for all the `True` values in the mask. Then it uses NumPy's `.diff()` function to identify discontinuity in the indices. Inside the `for` loop it splits up the mask at the location of each identified discontinuity. Once that is complete I can use the now separate sets of indices to slice out the desired segments of data from my original `DataFrame`. See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')

idx = np.where((df['Temp'] > 23) & (df['Temp'] < 30))[0]
discontinuity = np.where(np.diff(idx) > 1)[0]
intervals = {}

for i in range(len(discontinuity)+1):
    if i == 0:
        intervals[i] = df.iloc[idx[0]:idx[discontinuity[i]],1]
        if len(intervals[i].values) < 1:
            del intervals[i]
    elif i == len(discontinuity):
        intervals[i] = df.iloc[idx[discontinuity[i-1]+1]:idx[-1],1]
        if len(intervals[i].values) < 1:
            del intervals[i]
    else:
        intervals[i] = df.iloc[idx[discontinuity[i-1]+1]:idx[discontinuity[i]],1] 
        if len(intervals[i].values) < 1:
            del intervals[i]


df1 = df.loc[intervals[0].index, :]
df2 = df.loc[intervals[1].index, :]
```

`df1` and `df2` contain all the data in the original `DataFrame` corresponding with the times (rows) that `'Temp'` is between 23 and 30.

`df1`:

```
       Date      Time  Pressure   Temp  Flow  Valve Position
3  3/5/2020  12:00:04      5.38  23.51   103            0.90
4  3/5/2020  12:00:05      5.42  24.27    99            0.89
5  3/5/2020  12:00:06      5.49  25.91    92            0.85
6  3/5/2020  12:00:07      5.55  26.78    85            0.82
```

`df2`:

```
        Date      Time  Pressure   Temp  Flow  Valve Position
10  3/5/2020  12:00:11      5.59  29.68   104            0.90
11  3/5/2020  12:00:12      5.53  24.55   111            0.93
12  3/5/2020  12:00:13      5.48  23.54   116            0.96
13  3/5/2020  12:00:14      5.44  23.11   119            1.00
```

I am glad I was able to get this to work for me and I can live with the couple lines that get lost using this method but I know this is a really pedestrian approach and I can't help but think someone who is not a python beginning could do the same thing much more cleanly and efficiently.

Could `groupby` from itertools or pandas work for this? I haven't been able to find a way to make that work.

Comment: do u mind posting the output for df1 and df2

Comment: also in the sample dataset you shared, none of the values in temp column meet the requirement in idx - none is greater than 23

Comment: @sammywemmy I added the two output dfs. That condition should find two chunks of data in the original table that meet the temp conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I think your code can be simplified as such:

```
# Get the subset that fulfills your conditions

df_conditioned = df.query('Temp > 23 and Temp < 30').copy()
```

```
# Check for discontinuities by looking at the indices
# I created a new column called 'Group' to keep track of the continuous indices

indices = df_conditioned.index.to_series()
df_conditioned['Group'] = ((indices - indices.shift(1)) != 1).cumsum()
```

```
# Store the groups (segments with same group number) as individual frames in a list

df_list = []
for group in df_conditioned['Group'].unique():
    df_list.append(df_conditioned.query('Group == @group').drop(columns='Group'))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow that is so much simpler. I had not come across`query` before. Also `@group` is new to me here, is that still a decorator in this case? I assume its how you are telling `query` that the lower case 'group' is the for loop iterator not a column header, correct? My only concern is the amount of memory that could be used by copying the data from the original `DataFrame` to `df_conditioned`. I sometimes run this code on very large files with days of 1 hz data, do you think having that copy as an intermediate will be an issue?

Comment: You are correct, `@group` is the loop iterator. It is not a python decorator, just the way syntax is written for `query`. `query` is useful when you are extracting a column based on simple expression. Actually, since you are able to load the original dataframe at once without memory issue, you can overwrite the original dataframe during the first query `df = df.query('Temp > 23 and Temp < 30)` if you don't need the remaining dataframe that doesn't meet the temperature query criteria.

Comment: @Toukenize could you provide a more elaborate explanation of what you have done? Maybe with some step by step examples? Excellent code though!